# How to prevent page elements from moving on different screen resolutions...?

Tags: html, css, position, element, dreamweaver

I'm new to web design/development and I'm currently in college taking a couple of web development and design courses. Right now I've been working on my fourth project but I'm having some trouble & kinda feel like I'm losing my mind with this one lol.


I'm using Dreamweaver to create the web pages, and when I preview the pages on the Chrome browser on my laptop (1920 x 1080), everything looks fine. But then when I preview the pages on a different screen resolution, all the page elements are messed up and my headings move all over the screen.


How do I make the page elements stay in the same position on all screen resolutions? As I've said, I'm pretty inexperienced so I'd really appreciate ANY help on this.


[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUVGyA7tissupvoo?open=lib%2Fscript.js) the code and CSS for one of the five web pages although I couldn't take out the CSS for the rest of the website so I apologize for it being long. Also, I apologize if I'm not even posting this correctly, this is my first time asking something on here.

```
h2.version-four {
    right: 840px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 254px;
    font-size: 1.9em;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are a noob:) so i use a css framework called bootstrap https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. W3school will get you through the noob stage of programming:)

Comment: I recommend you to studied flex, grid if you really want to be a web dev, understand these concepts will help you in the long run. In your project now, the easiest way is to stop using position absolute everywhere like this, and using other units like percent, em, rem, vh, vw instead of px.

Comment: @CoPham thanks for your reply. Where do you suggest I take position: absolute out of? I took it out of the heading tags but they still move partly off the screen when I view the page on a smaller screen resolution. I just basically need the heading tags to stay in place and not move around when the screen resolution changes. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this "https://codepen.io/vanco-pham/pen/ZEBPbbP?editors=1100" 
I do not recommend you just to copy it, try to understand why it works, and learn grid, flex as it will help you in the long run.

Comment: thank you for that. I checked it out but I'm not sure if the content will now cover the entire page because the background I designed is made in a way that I want the text content to start around more than half way down the page since I have a big photo under the nav. Here's what I mean : https://i.imgur.com/t3zQ4ET.png

Comment: In that case, just add a padding-top to the first section (with % or vh, not px) and use media query if needed. It will push everything down, you don't need to use position absolute on everything.

Comment: Okay, I added a padding-top to the first section but then it pushed everything including the nav down. How do I avoid pushing the nav down with the rest of the content?

Thanks.

Comment: You add padding-top to the section below the nav, the first section in your project is the section with the class name "one".

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with different @Media query rules, that is basically CSS rules per Specific Resolution that you choose.

If you are using dream weaver this will make things much easier.

Once you have your html and css files loaded. You just have to go in your CSS designer ---> Media and create a new rule for the Screen resolution you want to adapt your content to.

Examples: Max-width, min-width, min-height, max-height

[image: CSS Designer -Media Query]

After this is done, add the CSS class to this @Media rule you created and change the attributes as you want in order to fit your content appropriately through your CSS file or your dreamweaver CSS Designer. For preview you can drag the screen fitter to change resolutions on Live mode.

[image: Change Resolution]

Best Regards,

Jaso